# Cross account access from ec2 to other accounts

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-iam

Is it possible to run aws cli from ec2 to create some resources in another account without using aws_secret_key and aws_access_key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the scenario with two accounts A & B the explanatory steps should be:

1. In **account A**, I created a **role** (e.g `RoleForB`) to trust **account B**, and attach to the before created role a **IAM policy** to allow it to perform some read operations in **account A**. `e.g ReadOnlyAccess`
2. In **account B**, I created a **role** (e.g `AssumeRoleInA`) and attach a **policy** to allow it to assume the role that is created in **account A**.
3. In **account B** Associate to your EC2 instance `ec2-profile` the IAM role (`AssumeRoleInA`) created in step 2.
4. In **account B** login into this EC2 instance to **assume the role** in **Account A** using the command `aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB" --role-session-name "EC2FromB"`.
5. In **account B** EC2 terminal when the command is **step 4.** finished, you can see the **access key ID, secret access key, and session token** from wherever you've routed it, in our case `stdout` either manually or by using a script. You can then assign these values to environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`)

So Let’s check the configurations mentioned above step by step but with some mode detail:

1. As before presented in **account A**, it builds the trust to **account B** by creating the role named `RoleForB` and attaching `ReadOnlyAccess` permission to it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_ID:root"},
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

2. In **account B**, create a **role** named `AssumeRoleInA` then attach the corresponding `policy` to allow it to assume the role named `RoleForB` in **account A**.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

3. In **account B**, create a new **EC2 instance** (if it does not exists yet), and associate it's **ec2-profile** with the **IAM role** named `AssumeRoleInA`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

4. In **account B** login into this EC2 instance to **assume the role** in **Account A** using the command:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB" --role-session-name "EC2FromB"`
```

eg:

```
jenkins@bb-jenkins-vault:~$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::521111111144:role/DeployMaster --role-session-name "project-dev-jenkins-deploy"
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROAJBXGEHOQBXGEHOQ:project-dev-jenkins-deploy", 
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::521111111144:assumed-role/DeployMaster/project-dev-jenkins-deploy"
    }, 
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY", 
        "SessionToken": "FQoGZXIvYXCUm8iG6/zLdQ7foognvCDpxKP7cRJiZgc...CUm8iG6/zLdQ7foognvCDpxKP7c+OQF", 
        "Expiration": "2019-03-29T15:41:02Z", 
        "AccessKeyId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE"
    }
}
```

5. In **account B** EC2 terminal when the command is **step 4.** finished, you can see the **access key ID, secret access key, and session token** from wherever you've routed it, in our case `stdout` either manually or by using a script. You can then assign these values to environment variables

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
$ export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=FQoGZXIvYXCUm8iG6/zLdQ...<remainder of security token>
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1
```

**credit:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/55420220/6657158

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if the EC2 role allows `STS::AssumeRole` you can assume a role in the other account and get temporary credentials to do whatever you need to do in the other account.

See for example here: **[Cross Account Access with AWS-CLI](https://aws.nz/best-practice/cross-account-access-with-aws-cli/)**

Comment: Thank you Mlu. I don't want to use access_key and secret_key inside ec2. Is it possible without aws config file(aws/credential) has access to other accounts?

Comment: @Pzowghi AWS-CLI can use your *EC2 IAM Role* to get local credentials and then use those to *assume role* in the other account to get temporary creds from there. No access/secret keys on the filesystem involved.

Comment: I understand the concept. You shared the solution but there are access and secret key in that. If I don't have aws/credentials and aws/config how I could have different profiles for different accounts?

Comment: @Pzowghi Ah, true. Skip that first step, aws-cli will get the creds from EC2 IAM role by default.